# Is there any printing app for ios that supports Hp laserjet 4050 N Series

Tags: printing, network-printer, ios, hp-laserjet

Is there any printing app for ios that supports hp laserjet 4050 N series. I tried printer pro but when i print a test page a message says on the screen of the printer saying "chosen language not supported". I did install the desktop app for this but i have to always turn on my computer which is a bit annoying to do. So is there any?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use [HP eprint](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hp.android.print&hl=en) app, which will resolve this issue. Also this app support large size paper print.